# AngularJS + Spring Project architecture

Tags: java, spring, angularjs, architecture, jersey

I am planning to start a project and I am looking for the best approach to make a RIA application using AngularJS.

Right know I am pretty sure of those technologies:

1. AngularJS (+ bootstrap CSS) for the client UI, logic and server
   requests.
2. Spring for bootstrapping the server business logic.
3. Hibernate + MySQL for persistent data access
4. Jersey for the Restful web service API.
5. Spring Security for url and data protection over authentication.

The only piece I feel is not ok is that my application will not be the typical one page app, because it will be large and I want to break it into multiple one page apps, some protected and others public. To serve every index.html I want another technology like Spring MVC, making those small one page apps secure for this points, and also not allowing the access to some resources.

¿Do you think this is a good approach or you would change any of this technologies (like supressing jersey/Spring MVC redundant dependencies)?

Comment: You can use `Spring` cotrollers for `*.jsp` files (index pages, angular.js templates) and rest api calls. And also if you want to split your `*.js` files between pages, take a look at `require.js`

Comment: You'll save time and typing using Spring Data REST over Jersey.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendations! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think that in general your aprroach is a good one, but maybe you could use the webapp generator [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) with the [JHispster](http://jhipster.github.io/), a java web app generator. 
Or if you don't like the ideia you could add to your data access layer the [Spring-Data-JPA](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/), because you will avoid to write the boilerplate code.

Comment: Wow, I did not know about JHipster but looks pretty well. And about spring data, I have thought on, but need some test to know how it works. If finally JHipster gives me what I want, I will give you the tick.